# IFS has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 1. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1000, column count: 1

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, nested-if, ifs

My formula is as follows:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFS(AND(H2:H >= -B39, H2:H <= B40), 100, H2:H > B37, 0))
```

However this line keeps throwing the error:

```
IFS has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 1. column count: 1. Actual row count: 1000, column count: 1.
```

Any idea how to fix this?

I have similar formulaes like this one that works:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFS(F2:F <= 0, 100, F2:F >= B19, 0, true, (B19 - F2:F) / B19 * 100))
```

Not sure what I'm doing so differently with the first formula that would cause the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AND` is not supported under `ARRAYFORMULA`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFS((H2:H >= -B39)*(H2:H <= B40), 100, H2:H > B37, 0))
```

and `IFS` is in some cases not suited for `ARRAYFORMULA` as well

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((H2:H >= -B39)*(H2:H <= B40), 100, IF( H2:H > B37, 0, )))
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm just wondering how was I supposed to know this. Is it documented somewhere? The error for sure is miss leading...

Comment: @Waltari of course it not documented, like a lots of other stuff

Comment: Of course :D ...